# Postgresql: Split line into 4 lines

Tags: sql, postgresql

My concern is to split a single line into 4 lines using a SQL script.
It is that I get in an SQL Result the year, the quarter, the month and a x worthy value. Now I would also like to spend the week of the month (1-4) without having to add this as a column of the table.
Likewise, the value should be divided by four.
Thus, from this result:

```
year | quarter | month | value
2016 | 1       | 1     | 78954
```

This result:

```
year | quarter | month | week | value
2016 | 1       | 1     | 1    | 19738,5
2016 | 1       | 1     | 2    | 19738,5
2016 | 1       | 1     | 3    | 19738,5
2016 | 1       | 1     | 4    | 19738,5
```

I have no idea how I could implement this.
I hope anyone can help me.

Best regards

Comment: there are more weeks in one month then 4

Comment: But how can i check this in a sql query @VaoTsun ?

Comment: well if you care weeks, you should probably use wook of the year, like `select extract(week from now());` would give you 50. It does not solve the problem that 52th week of running year is first week of next. But at least  approximation it 10x better. Anyway if you do care, you should think another question - this one is brilliantly answered by Sami yet

Comment: Though you have got two answers and accepted one, I think you are barking up the wrong tree. The 4 times union and the cartesian join will both be horribly slow and not accurate. As @VaoTsun has pointed out a month has more than four weeks.

Comment: @e4c5: but a month will never have more then 4 **complete** weeks.

Comment: but @horse_with_no_name all months except february have at least thirty days, which is 4 days and 2/7s

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but ~half of the months usually have less than 4 **complete** weeks, so what's the point? Months are not dividable by weeks. OP could clarify the reason, that he wants to achieve with this (or at least define what to do with truncated weeks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with a cartesian join:

```
SELECT a.year, a.quarter, a.month, b.week, a.value
  FROM a, (SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4]) as week) b
```

Comment: You forget to divide `a.value` with `4.0`

Comment: @pozs that is not that bad

Answer (score 0):

Just use `union`:

```
select year, quarter, month, 1 as week, value / 4 as value
union all
select year, quarter, month, 2 as week, value / 4 as value
union all
select year, quarter, month, 3 as week, value / 4 as value
union all
select year, quarter, month, 4 as week, value / 4 as value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `generate_series()  for that:

```
select t.year, t.quarter, t.month, w.week, t.value / 4
from the_table t
 cross join generate_series(1,4) as w(week)
order by t.year, t.quarter, w.week;
```

Using `generate_series()` is more flexible if you need to change the number of repeated rows you want - although "weeks per quarter" doesn't really need that flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it in very scientifically looking way :-)

```
WITH series as (select generate_series(1,4,1) as week ),
  data as (SELECT 2016 as year, 1 as quarter, 1 as month, 78954 as value)
  SELECT d.year, d.quarter, d.month, s.week, d.value/(SELECT count(*) FROM series)::numeric 
  FROM data d JOIN series s ON true
```