# Postgresql: Divide a line in 4 lines with consecutive numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql

According to my first question today on this topic ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41181071/postgresql-split-line-into-4-lines)), presents me a further.
I have the following SQL Result: Year, Quarter, Month, Week, and an x worthy value. Currently, I give the numbers 1-4 per month. However, I would now like to spend up to 52 consecutive numbers and only 4 for a month.

That is, from the following result:

```
year | quarter | month | week | value
2016 | 1       | 1     | 1    | 19738,5
2016 | 1       | 1     | 2    | 19738,5
2016 | 1       | 1     | 3    | 19738,5
2016 | 1       | 1     | 4    | 19738,5
```

Should this become:

```
year | quarter | month | week | value
2016 | 1       | 1     | 1    | 19738,5
2016 | 1       | 1     | 2    | 19738,5
2016 | 1       | 1     | 3    | 19738,5
2016 | 1       | 1     | 4    | 19738,5
2016 | 1       | 2     | 5    | 19738,5
2016 | 1       | 2     | 6    | 19738,5
2016 | 1       | 2     | 7    | 19738,5
2016 | 1       | 2     | 8    | 19738,5
```

Zu diesem Zeitpunkt lautet die Query so:

```
SELECT a.year, a.quarter, a.month, b.week AS week, sum(a.points) AS value
FROM
    TABLE AS a,
    (SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4]) as week) AS b
GROUP BY
    year,
    quarter,
    month,
    week;
```

Also, I have unfortunately no ideas and hope for your help.

Comment: You should edit your question and include the query in your question.

Comment: Most of the months have 30 or 31 days (<> 4 weeks).

Comment: @GordonLinoff i had added the query

Comment: Has this table a datetime field?

Comment: Your week numbers will never reach 52, as only 12 months are in a year (and your "interpretation" of week-of-month -- i.e. it has always 4 of them -- will only make 48 weeks total, no matter what).

Comment: @mcNets no it has not, that is the problem

Comment: @pozs Okay, you're right. But how could I make it that the 52 week comes?

Comment: That depends on how do you want to calculate the `value` on truncated weeks? (i.e. a week, which has only 3 days in the given month would get `3/7` of the value for a week which is completely in the given month?) And also, do you want weeks, which are cut half to be in both of the affected months? (i.e. do you want a `Y2016 Q4 M11 W48` **and** a `Y2016 Q4 M12 W48` row too? -- because W48 was from 2016-11-28 to 2016-12-04)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you have 12 records, one by month. And there is no datetime where to extract month, quarter, week, ...

I modified the previous answer by adding `row_number()` as a week number.

Keep in mind that:

**This is not the real week number**

It simply divide every month by 4, and this means 48 weeks a year.

```
select year, month, quarter,
           row_number() over (partition by year order by year,month,quarter) as week,
           value / 4 as week_value
    from t1,
        (SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4])) b;
```

Check it here: http://rextester.com/XUQRK94308

Comment: Thank you this is what i need. I know that this is not the real week number. I hope i find a solution for that problem but at the moment this is okay. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can bond the running week to the running month - if week started in Feb it belongs to Feb, no matter it ends in March, if so, you can `JOIN` em like here:

```
t=# select
  wom "week of month", mn "month", wn "week", amount/max(wom) over(partition by mn)
from (
with
  weeks as (select generate_series('2016-01-01'::date,'2017-01-01'::date,'1 week'::interval) w)
, months as ( select generate_series('2016-01-01'::date,'2017-01-01'::date,'1 month'::interval) m)
select *, 78954 amount, dense_rank() over (partition by m order by w) wom, dense_rank() over (order by m) mn, dense_rank() over (order by w) wn
from weeks
join months on date_trunc('month',w) = m
) p
;
 week of month | month | week | ?column?
---------------+-------+------+----------
             1 |     1 |    1 |    15790
             2 |     1 |    2 |    15790
             3 |     1 |    3 |    15790
             4 |     1 |    4 |    15790
             5 |     1 |    5 |    15790
             1 |     2 |    6 |    19738
             2 |     2 |    7 |    19738
             3 |     2 |    8 |    19738
             4 |     2 |    9 |    19738
             1 |     3 |   10 |    19738
             2 |     3 |   11 |    19738
             3 |     3 |   12 |    19738
             4 |     3 |   13 |    19738
             1 |     4 |   14 |    15790
             2 |     4 |   15 |    15790
             3 |     4 |   16 |    15790
             4 |     4 |   17 |    15790
             5 |     4 |   18 |    15790
             1 |     5 |   19 |    19738
             2 |     5 |   20 |    19738
             3 |     5 |   21 |    19738
             4 |     5 |   22 |    19738
             1 |     6 |   23 |    19738
             2 |     6 |   24 |    19738
             3 |     6 |   25 |    19738
             4 |     6 |   26 |    19738
             1 |     7 |   27 |    15790
             2 |     7 |   28 |    15790
             3 |     7 |   29 |    15790
             4 |     7 |   30 |    15790
             5 |     7 |   31 |    15790
             1 |     8 |   32 |    19738
             2 |     8 |   33 |    19738
             3 |     8 |   34 |    19738
             4 |     8 |   35 |    19738
             1 |     9 |   36 |    15790
             2 |     9 |   37 |    15790
             3 |     9 |   38 |    15790
             4 |     9 |   39 |    15790
             5 |     9 |   40 |    15790
             1 |    10 |   41 |    19738
             2 |    10 |   42 |    19738
             3 |    10 |   43 |    19738
             4 |    10 |   44 |    19738
             1 |    11 |   45 |    19738
             2 |    11 |   46 |    19738
             3 |    11 |   47 |    19738
             4 |    11 |   48 |    19738
             1 |    12 |   49 |    15790
             2 |    12 |   50 |    15790
             3 |    12 |   51 |    15790
             4 |    12 |   52 |    15790
             5 |    12 |   53 |    15790
(53 rows)
```